# How to define HTML tag with specific ID in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to apply/bind event only on specific `DIV ID` and `Textarea`. Then How can I achieve this?

I have below code

```
jQuery("#dataContent").bind("click change keypress"....){
    .....
}
```

I want to apply above three events only on `Textarea` and not on other HTML elements. Then How can I achieve this?

Can I do like below?

```
jQuery("#dataContent textarea")
```

Because currently above three events creating issue with `file input` and `checkbox`.

Any help would be heartily appreciated :)

**Note: I'm facing this issue since long and not able to resolve it till today :(**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can like,

```
$("#dataContent textarea").on("click, change, keypress", function() {

});
```

**OR**

```
$("#dataContent").on("click, change, keypress","textarea", function() {

});
```

You can use it like

```
$( "#dataContent textarea" ).on({
   click: function() {
       alert("click");
   }, change: function() {
       alert("change");
   }, keypress: function() {
       alert("keypress");
   }
});
```

Read [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/YzncD/)

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this.

```
$("#dataContent").on("click, change, keypress", function() {

});
```

[reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dataContent ")
.on("click, change, keypress","textarea", function() {

});
```

reference **[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: How can I exclude checkbox and fileinput or any other HTML tags other than Textarea? And will work comma (,) as event separator?

Comment: @Rituraj if you are using `textarea` as `second parameter` in `on()` then why you are using `not()` to `exclude input elements` ,and if I want to `exclude type="email", type="date"` then you will append the list of `input elements` in `not()`? You can not use **$("#dataContent ").not("input").** for all `input elements`?

Comment: thanks for focus  @RohanKumar some times it happen :)